# How to generate authorization information per API endpoint in Swagger Doc based on Spring-Security annotations

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, swagger, springfox

How to reuse Spring-Security annotations like `@PreAuthorize` or `@Secured` in Springfox-swagger to avoid maintaining the authorization information twice?

Currently the only options I found to populate security information in the swagger.json is duplicating the role information with swagger-core annotations like

```
@Secured(ROLE_USER)
@ApiOperation(value = "Get the model", authorizations = { 
    @Authorization(value = ROLE_USER) })
@GetMapping(value = "model/**")
```

or specifying globally in the SwaggerConfig::

```
private SecurityContext apiSecurityContext() {
        AuthorizationScope[] authorizationScopes = new AuthorizationScope[] { new AuthorizationScope(Roles.ROLE_USER, "access limited"),
                new AuthorizationScope(Roles.ROLE_ADMIN, "access Everything") };

        return SecurityContext
                .builder()
                .securityReferences(newArrayList(new SecurityReference("basic", authorizationScopes)))
                .forPaths(PathSelectors.regex("/api.*")) // (PathSelectors.any())
                .build();
    }
```

Both ways seems not to be a good solution since I need to maintain the information multiple times or are not precise.

So what do I need to configure in order to let swagger depict the authorization roles a requester needs to access a certain rest resource from the spring-security annotations?

Comment: `@Authorization(value= ROLE_USER)`is not correct, because the value is the authorization scheme, in your example it should be basic. Swagger doesn't support roles. And `@AuthorizationScope` is only used for OAuth2 scopes. It is not used for any other authentication (for example basic authentication). Hence, your code is not conform to the spec, because scopes are not roles.

Comment: I agree, that is a missing feature, but at least you don't need to write it twice.

Comment: Thanks for making this clear. I wasn't aware that Swagger doesn't support roles